# Best Dedicated Hosting with RAID 1 and managed backup

Tags: web-hosting, backups

I run a (CentOS-powered) website currently, and we are currently planning on moving to a dedicated server. One of the essentials for us is *preventing data loss with the least amount of bother*. Therefore, I feel that the following features are important for us

- RAID 1
- Managed backups by the hosting company, with at least a 7 day retention

In my search for providers, I found some which provide RAID 1, but none apart from GoDaddy which provide Managed backups. 1&1 provides "FTP backup bandwidth", but I have to provide the backup location myself.

Am I missing something? Are there other reputable hosting providers which can provide managed backups as part of their dedicated hosting plans? Some pointers will be much appreciated.

Thanks,
-A

Comment: Since this is an opinion poll, I'm making it community wiki.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[Memset](http://www.memset.com/backups.php) are quite good. Kate Craig-Wood, the MD, runs quite a tight ship and we are informed of unexpected outages in under 2 minutes (two lasting 30 minutes approx in the last year). You also get follow up reports on what happened.

[RackSpace](http://www.rackspace.com/managed_hosting/services/storage/managedbackup.php) also offer managed backup, but I personally cannot trust a company offering "100% uptime", let alone receiving no compensation when their inter-networking of servers changed from 1-3ms to over 500ms per packet. Although many friends and popular on-line SASS companies rave about them.

Comment: Thanks. These comments are very helpful. Sorry I do not have enough reputation points to vote it up :-\.

Comment: Thats OK - hope you find a hosting provider that suits.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a big fan of http://www.aiso.net/  Besides the fact that they are entirely (100%, onsite) solar powered, and that they host major sites like the Discovery network, they also run a great virtualized setup that I think will become the future of hosting.  One of the side benefits of their solution is hourly snapshots and immediate cloning of servers in the event of --reboot-- or restart.  I used snapshots quite a few times and they were worth their weight in gold, with such a simple system for retrieving that I was amazed.

100% uptime is virtually impossible, but it certainly helps to be the only host on the planet who can say that they've never used power from the (unreliable) grid.  Even if you don't choose their hosting, the site has some interesting information that appeals to the geek in us.

Answer (score 0):

Oneandone do provide me with FTP backup space, included with my dedicated servers (I've forgotten how much, but I'm pretty sure it's multiple GB). However, aside from that I wouldn't recommend them.